# Large image making webpage slow

Tags: html, image, css, adobe-illustrator

I have a large image I want to use for a food menu for my website. I don't want to attempt to replicate it using  unless that's my only option. Currently the image is a 3.9MB.png file that I made in Illustrator. I would like to keep the quality of the image and make it universal on all platforms (tablet, laptop, phone).

Comment: I suggest to do some research on SVG - they are perfect solution for graphics made in Ai, resolution independent, light in size and web friendly

Comment: Thank you, I will! Is it possible to open the .png in AI and convert it to SVG to get the perks?

Comment: No.  Images like PNG and JPEG are *raster* images, whereas SVG is *vector*. Search and learn.

Comment: [https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) - should give you a good starting point to start using svg's on web projects. You said that you made this file in Illustrator,  you can simply save it as svg file instead. SVG's are good for graphics, but if you try to make a vector out of photograph, it is not a good idea, and you'll end up in equally large file.

Answer (score 1):

I do suggest that u can convert it to jpg file type.

3.9mb is too large for web page, especially for tablet. However, after convert into jpg type, the quality is not impacted as much as you think. Why not try jpg first, as jpg is perfect for web image.

Sorry I do not have nice format in response, as I answer in my mobile phone.

Try jpg and good luck.

Comment: I did. It reduced the image to 1.9mb. Unfortunately the page still lags.

Comment: May i ask your resolution of your picture?
Basicly, if jpg type, it should not occupy 1.9M, even in full screen.
You should not let html resize your picture. It will damage your website's performance.

Answer (score 0):

Optimize the png using any online tool like https://tinypng.com/.

Comment: If a PNG is 3.9 MB, this means it has relative huge dimensions. huge raster graphics should be delivered as JPEG on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Open the image again and this time use ** file -> save for web option **
choose Jpeg and quality level to high or very high
the image file size will be reducing without affecting its clarity.